# Get the rows based on the indexes and then create another separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a code to extract the index from a dataframe but I do not know how to use these indexes to create another dataframe from the original dataframe.

Is it possible to shorten my current code too? Its quite long.

EDITED==

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"a":["I have something", "I have nothing", "she has something", "she is nice", "she is not nice","Me", "He"],
                 "b":[["man"], ["man", "eating"], ["cat"], ["man"], ["cat"], ["man"], ["cat"]]})
a = a[a.b.apply(lambda x:len(x)) == 1] # is it possible to shorten the code from here
c = a.explode("b").groupby("b")
k = ["man", "cat"]
bb = a
for x in k:
    bb = c.get_group(x).head(2).index # to here?.... this part is supposed to take the first 2 indexes of each element in k
```

Current results:

```
    a       b
4   she is not nice [cat]

Expected results:


    a       b
0   I have something    [man]
2   she has something   [cat]
3   she is nice [man]
4   she is not nice [cat]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First filter by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and then convert one element string to string, so possible test duplicity by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html). Invert boolean mask by `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
a = a[a.b.str.len() == 1]

b = a[~a['b'].str[0].duplicated()]
print (b)
                 a      b
3      she is nice  [man]
4  she is not nice  [cat]
```

EDIT: For multiple values use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
b1 = a.groupby(a['b'].str[0]).head(2)
print (b1)
                   a      b
0   I have something  [man]
2  she has something  [cat]
3        she is nice  [man]
4    she is not nice  [cat]
```

Comment: Thank you sir but can I know what is the "~" stands for and the duplicated too?

Comment: No, it is for invert boolean mask. Give me sec for explanation

Comment: Sorry sir, I made a mistake and has already updated what I wanted to find. For example, what I want is to take the first 2 data for each "man" and "cat". And not about getting the duplicate.